# Plot y1 in x1 with respect to x2 axis

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data a follows:

```
y1   x1   x2
125  100   1
130  90    2
136  85    3
143  70    4
145  65    5
```

I would like to plot it in gnuplot as in the figure.[image]

I used the procedure mentioned here [Gnuplot: Plot x2 axis with respect to x1 axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19121823/gnuplot-plot-x2-axis-with-respect-to-x1-axis) , but it is plotting the x2 differently.

Comment: In order to do what you ask for, the series `x1` and `x2` should be affinely related (`x2 = a x1 + b`), which is not the case here. Maybe you're looking for customized x labels, see `set xlabel ("label" pos, ...)` syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plot your data as usual on the x1 and y1 axes, but place additional labels on the x2-axis with `x2tic(3)`:

```
set xrange [*:*] reverse
set x2tics
set xtics nomirror
plot 'file.dat' using 2:1:x2tic(3) with linespoints pt 7 notitle
```

[image]

If you don't want a conventional numerical, you could also use both `x2tic` and `xtic`:

```
plot 'file.dat' using 2:1:x2tic(3):xtic(2) with linespoints pt 7 notitle
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Christoph, thank you very much for this answer. Would you please suggest how to set the xtics so that they will not overlap. I have asked the same problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40540269/plot-y1-in-x1-with-respect-to-x2-axis-without-overlapping-the-xtics-values