# Gnuplot - link x1 and x2 axes via dataset, instead of function

Tags: gnuplot

A similar question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19121823/gnuplot-plot-x2-axis-with-respect-to-x1-axis). Basically, I have three columns (A, B, C) and they represent measurements A(B) and C(B). Say, B is time, A temperature and C any other physical quantity that depends on A.

I would like to plot on `x1` temperature, on `x2` time and on y1 `C` as it evolves with time. The mentioned solution works for a few datapoints but is not usable for a larger dataset because it essentially modifies the labels and I lose control over the labels. I would like the plot to look like:
[image]
with temperature on the `x1` axis in a nice form that is something like:
[image]
Obviously they will not be initially equidistant because the relationship between temperature and time is:
[image]

Any idea how to approach this? The test data is here
https://pastebin.com/CqAHjBJe

Comment: Please provide some minimal test data.

Comment: @theozh Apologies, i forgot. Updated.

Comment: Could I recommend you to retitle the question as like "Gnuplot - link x1 and x2 axes via dataset, instead of function"?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you want to link x1 and x2 axes, correct? For this you need an expression and the inverse of it. Check `help link`.

I would say that this makes only sense in the range of your (linear?!) temperature increase over time. From the graph, I read the values:

```
# Time
t0 = 73
t1 = 287
# Temperature
T0 = 179
T1 = 1252
```

I guess, one could also think about a way to extract these values automatically.

**Script:**

```
### link x1 and x2 axes
reset session

FILE = "SO76860010.dat"

# Time
t0 = 73
t1 = 287
# Temperature
T0 = 179
T1 = 1252

set datafile separator comma
set xlabel "Time"
set xrange[t0:t1]
set xtics nomirror

set x2label "Temperature"
set link x2 via (x-t0)*real(T1-T0)/(t1-t0) + T0 inverse (x-T0)*real(t1-t0)/(T1-T0) + t0
set x2tics 100
set grid x2,y

set ylabel "Quantity"
set key noautotitle

plot FILE u 2:3 w l lc "red"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: If you look at the plot of `t` vs `T` there is no simple functional relationship between them. `T` is measured as a function of `t`, and while ideally there is a functional relationship that was input into the machine, there is no reason to assume that the machine followed it exactly (you can see it at several points that the temperature overshoots the target). For that reason, `set link` is not a good option.

Comment: @atapaka so far, for me the values of an axis were either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing but not both. You can either plot your quantity versus time or versus temperature. I don't see how you want to "link" two axes if one is not monotonic. Well, you could go to 3D. x=time, y=temparature, z=quantity.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you want something like this:

[image]

```
reset; set datafile separator "\t ,";
set grid x2tics ytics
set xlabel 'Temperature'
set ylabel 'signal'
set x2label 'time' offset 0,-0.5

set xtics nomirror
set x2tics nomirror

set xrange[0:300]
set x2range[0:300]

plot '013_d2.dat' u 2:3:xtic("".int($1)) every 100 axes x2y1 w d lc 1 notitle ,\
'' u 2:3 axes x2y1 w l lc 1 t 'Measurement'
```

The key of the solution is assigning some of your time data to the `xtics` by:
`using 2:3:xtics(1)`. However, you have too much data, therefore you have to make them fewer by `every`.

For a better look, you can round your temperature data by `int($1/10)*10`

If you want to examine the code, use it without the `w d` and `lc` specifiers.

**EDIT:** I have updated the answer using your data provided.

**EDIT2:** I have updated the answer reversing the x1-x2 axes (as the OP originally wanted).

Comment: Although this might be what OP wants, but the plotted data together with the x2-axis is not correct or at least misleading. The real curve doesn't go backwards in time.

Comment: @theozh Tom Solid did it vice versa. The plot should have been `Column(3)` (y-axis) as a function of time (on `x2` axis) and then put the corresponding temperatures on the x1 axis. This is really what i wanted. This is because, the physical dependence of some value (think e.g. of amount of water in a sample) is on temperature but in an experiment, don't really control temperature but by measuring it, you adjust power in the heating element (or think of an isothermal step at a temperature to remove adsorbed water which causes that loop around 180C) and the only monoincreasing variable is time.

Comment: @atapaka I beg your pardon. I'm used to x1 being the main axis and x2 the auxiliary one.